# How can I find the last item in a subset of an angular ng-repeat loop?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**The last item in the labels element isn't necessarily checked, so $last won't work.** It results in this:
    peaches, bananas, cherries, watermelon,

How do I find the last item in an angular ng-repeat using an ng-if as a filter and append a comma to all but the last checked item in the list?

I have a list of values that will be concatenated in my view. A sample list would be:

```
model.labels = {
    value0: {
        label: 'peaches',
        checked: true
    },
    value1: {
        label: 'apples',
        checked: false
    },
    value2: {
        label: 'bananas',
        checked: true
    },
    value3: {
        label: 'cherries',
        checked: true
    },
    value4: {
        label: 'watermelon',
        checked: true
    },
    value5: {
        label: 'plums',
        checked: false
    },
    value6: {
        label: 'mangos',
        checked: false
    }
}
```

Essentially what I want is what I have in my view already with the caveat that the last item in the labels element isn't necessarily checked, so $last won't work:

`<span ng-repeat="label in model.labels" ng-if="label.checked">
{{label.label}}{{$last ? '' : ', '}}
</span>`

I've considered a custom filter, adding a new object to the model in the controller that contains a pre-concatenated string, and an html solution using a repeated span containing a comma that is hidden using span:last-of-type. I want to know if there's a solution without doing any of the above three.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, did you read the entire question before marking it as a duplicate?

Comment: Sorry if I had wrongly dupe hammered, which now has been already reverted. Sorry for the confusion caused.

Comment: This might help you, this guy got relatively same problem and asked to angular team. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13601

Comment: @PraveenKumar, no worries. Thanks for the followup.

Comment: @babidi, yep, that's exactly the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter):

```
<span ng-repeat="label in model.labels | filter:{checked: true}">
    {{label.label}}{{$last ? '' : ', '}}
</span>
```